# Are there volatility models dependent on returns?

Tags: option-pricing, volatility, stochastic-volatility

When I look at the relationship between volatility and price, I see a clear negative correlation as shown in this figure (SPY and VIX prices today looking back 1 year).
[image]

The common volatility models (GARCH, Heston, etc.) do not seem to exploit this correlation.  I'm sure they exist, but I just haven't found them.  Can anyone point me towards models that do?

Comment: The Heston model explicitly includes a stock-volatility correlation parameter $\rho$, which is of course strictly less than zero in nearly all practical use cases.

Answer (score 3):

The Heston model can have that property. If you make the correlation negative between the Brownian motions in the $dS_{t}$ process and the $d\nu_{t}$ process you imply that price is negatively correlated with variance.

Comment: This is key. I forgot (or didn't realize) the two noise sources in the Heston model are correlated.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah this is often called Spot-Vol correlation and is well known. Most people take this into account. I think if you just google spot-vol correlation you will come up with many example/models.